Should we burninate the [special-abilities] tag again?
Today, I discovered the special-abilities tag, which doesn't have any Tag Wiki entry and doesn't really seem like something that can be reasonably defined either. It's currently used on 14 questions.
Looking through meta, there was once a specialabilites tag, without the hyphen, back in 2018. Which was burninated, as discussed in this question: Make [specialabilities] not special
Am I correct to assume that we should burninate this tag once again? Should we also block the tag?

FYI, while you’re doing the bonus action cleanup , can you check the other tags for relevancy while you clean add bonus action? Nice work on site maintenance!

@NotArch Yeah, I saw your edits. I am personally unsure if Actions should maybe stay in that case because a Bonus Action is a subset of Actions, but you are probably right. The Bonus Action clean might take quite a while as there are 1500+ BA Questions, as of this query: "bonus action" [dnd-5e-2014] -[bonus-action] is:q

Important note: We burninated the tag in 2018 (meaning, removed it from all questions it was on) because it was being used in a way that wasn't considered particularly useful at the time. That may be different now. For example, the tag was recreated in 2023 for a question about a Blades in the Dark special ability, in which the mechanic in question is a special ability—that's the name of the thing the question is about—which would mean the tag was used entirely correctly there and removing it doesn't seem like it'd be the correct move.

@doppelgreener I see, then giving it a Tag wiki Entry and removing it from questions whose games don't have that terminology seems like the more logical solution.

@TreeSpawned I suspect that would be part of the correct resolution here, yeah.

If it's supposed to be a specific feature in Blades of the Dark, then it's better to be renamed to something like [blades-of-the-dark-special-ability] (or an acceptable acronym to shorten it). Otherwise it will always be at risk of being used for other games. And it's exceptionally unlikely that "special ability" carries the same connotation in all games that might use those words.

@VLAZ That would be an unusual precedent for us. We don't call them [fate-stunts], we call them [tag:stunts], and they share that tag with other games that also have a mechanic called stunts (e.g. a couple of age system questions). The “risk” of other games using the tag is basically not a risk, there's no harm considered to come from it.

We can already see how people didn't use the tag for that game only. And they've used it in the past before Blades of the Dark - there was a previous burnination. It was, is, and will be misused.

@VLAZ What I mean to illustrate is that “using the tag for one game only” is not a required behaviour; using it on multiple games is not a misuse. The previous burnination was not because of it being misused: it was a misspelled tag on only four questions where alternative tags covered the subject matter.

I must agree with both of you here. On the one hand it is not commenplace to name a tag after a system (e.g. [tag:bonus-action] specifically mentions D&D 5E but if another game were to also have bonus actions, of course it would also use this tag), but on the other hand "special-abilities" is such a generic term, that it is easy to misuse. I personally think an unmistakeble Wiki entry that states something like "Do not use this if it's not a specific rules term in your game" would be the solution here. If that doesn't work we can still rethink it.

Sift it through, add a descriptor
In contrast to the last time, this time we have an actual game mechanic that used that term in one game. Those can keep it. Others just need to lose it.
Someone needs to write a wiki entry and descriptor telling what it actually is for.

Now all we need is someone to volunteer and do that, which should probably be someone who knows the game(s) that has this term.

@TreeSpawned I added a description, following the discsusions above about its content. I did not go into the specifics of the special abilities, as each is different and there is little that is common across them, other than that they are limited to characters that chose a given playbook. (PBTA's loose but less restrictive equivalent to classes or roles).

@NobodytheHobgoblin Thank you very much. I have now removed the tag from all 5e questions. It still used by question about pathfinder 1e, D&D 3,5e and l5r 4e. Someone who has played/run those games should probably edit those, if that isn't a term in those games.
